# Looping through and merging DataFrames with same index, same columns (however a few columns unique to each DataFrame)

Tags: pandas, loops, dataframe, merge, concatenation

**Description of task required**

I use the following code to merge `df` and `df1` (example data shown) and it works well for what I have needed. However, I need to loop over a large number of DataFrames (`df2` for example, but will be `df3`, `df4` etc.) and am not sure how to amend the code. I have DataFrames with the same index, same columns, however a few columns are individual to each DataFrame. I use the following code and it works well, but I wish to amend it so I can loop through `df` and `df1`, merge them together, creating `requireddata` but then repeat this where `requireddata` is merged with `df2`. The same logic would continue with `requireddata` merging with `df3` and so on. Any help would be awesome!! :)

`df`

```
       ID    AA  TA  TL
Date                      
2001  AAPL   1.0  44  50 
2002  AAPL   3.0  33  51 
2003  AAPL   2.0  22  53 
2004  AAPL   5.0  11  76 
2005  AAPL   2.0  33  44 
2006  AAPL   3.0  22  12
```

`df1`

```
       ID    AA  TA  ML
Date                      
2001  MSFT   3.5  44  12
2002  MSFT   6.7  33  15
2003  MSFT   2.3  22  19
2004  MSFT   5.5  11  20
2005  MSFT   2.2  33  43
2006  MSFT   3.2  22  23
```

`df2` **Example**

```
       ID    AA  TA  PP
Date                      
2001  TSLA   3.3  48  18
2002  TSLA   6.3  38  18
2003  TSLA   2.6  28  18
2004  TSLA   5.3  18  28
2005  TSLA   2.3  38  48
2006  TSLA   3.3  28  28
```

**Code used**

```
dfdates['Date'] # this has dates required for index
df
df1

cols_to_use = df.columns.difference(df1.columns) #compare column difference df and df1
cols_to_use1 = df1.columns.difference(df.columns) #compare column difference df1 and df

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns = cols_to_use, index = df['Date']) #dataframe with columns in df1 but not in df
dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = cols_to_use1, index = df1['Date']) #dataframe with columns in df but not in df1

datatesting = pd.concat([dataframe, df], axis=1) #merge missing columns into df
datatesting1 = pd.concat([dataframe1, df1], axis=1) #merge missing columns into df1

diff = datatesting1.columns.difference(datatesting.columns) #check difference (is 0)
print (diff)
frames = [datatesting, datatesting1] #list of dataframes 
requireddata = pd.concat(frames) #merge dataframes
```

**Creates this:**

```
       ID    AA   TA   TL  ML
Date                      
2001  AAPL   1.0  44  50  NaN
2002  AAPL   3.0  33  51  NaN
2003  AAPL   2.0  22  53  NaN
2004  AAPL   5.0  11  76  NaN
2005  AAPL   2.0  33  44  NaN
2006  AAPL   3.0  22  12  NaN                    
2001  MSFT   3.5  44  NaN  12
2002  MSFT   6.7  33  NaN  15
2003  MSFT   2.3  22  NaN  19
2004  MSFT   5.5  11  NaN  20
2005  MSFT   2.2  33  NaN  43
2006  MSFT   3.2  22  NaN  23
```

**With looping code, would love for something like this:**

```
       ID    AA   TA   TL  ML  PP
Date                      
2001  AAPL   1.0  44  50  NaN  NaN
2002  AAPL   3.0  33  51  NaN  NaN
2003  AAPL   2.0  22  53  NaN  NaN
2004  AAPL   5.0  11  76  NaN  NaN
2005  AAPL   2.0  33  44  NaN  NaN
2006  AAPL   3.0  22  12  NaN  NaN                  
2001  MSFT   3.5  44  NaN  12  NaN
2002  MSFT   6.7  33  NaN  15  NaN
2003  MSFT   2.3  22  NaN  19  NaN
2004  MSFT   5.5  11  NaN  20  NaN
2005  MSFT   2.2  33  NaN  43  NaN
2006  MSFT   3.2  22  NaN  23  NaN
2001  TSLA   3.3  48  NaN  NaN  18
2002  TSLA   6.3  38  NaN  NaN  18
2003  TSLA   2.6  28  NaN  NaN  18
2004  TSLA   5.3  18  NaN  NaN  28
2005  TSLA   2.3  38  NaN  NaN  48
2006  TSLA   3.3  28  NaN  NaN  28
```

Comment: IIUC, u r merging the dataframes into one. why not just concatenate the dataframes? pd.concat([df,df1,df2]). are there other rules you did not mention?

Comment: If I were you I will use a MultiIndex with Date and ID

Comment: If you want concat `pd.concat([df,df1,df2],sort = False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe columns difference is not necessary here, only use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), columns are aligned correctly:

```
df = pd.concat([df,df1,df2], sort=False)
print (df)
        ID   AA  TA    TL    ML    PP
Date                                 
2001  AAPL  1.0  44  50.0   NaN   NaN
2002  AAPL  3.0  33  51.0   NaN   NaN
2003  AAPL  2.0  22  53.0   NaN   NaN
2004  AAPL  5.0  11  76.0   NaN   NaN
2005  AAPL  2.0  33  44.0   NaN   NaN
2006  AAPL  3.0  22  12.0   NaN   NaN
2001  MSFT  3.5  44   NaN  12.0   NaN
2002  MSFT  6.7  33   NaN  15.0   NaN
2003  MSFT  2.3  22   NaN  19.0   NaN
2004  MSFT  5.5  11   NaN  20.0   NaN
2005  MSFT  2.2  33   NaN  43.0   NaN
2006  MSFT  3.2  22   NaN  23.0   NaN
2001  TSLA  3.3  48   NaN   NaN  18.0
2002  TSLA  6.3  38   NaN   NaN  18.0
2003  TSLA  2.6  28   NaN   NaN  18.0
2004  TSLA  5.3  18   NaN   NaN  28.0
2005  TSLA  2.3  38   NaN   NaN  48.0
2006  TSLA  3.3  28   NaN   NaN  28.0
```